# Content editor disappear

Tags: content-editor-web-part

So I have a little problem. I have a content editor that I want to edit the title of, but every time I enter edit mode the content editor disappears.

The content editor is in the hillbilly tabs so I thought that might be at play. when I took out the hillbilly tabs it still didn't solve the issue.

Any ideas?

Comment: Could you provide more details? Is the master page customized? Is any other script being loaded in the page?

Comment: I had faced this issue with Wiki Pages.. and ended up using Webpart Pages